# How can I make a new static variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, variables, static

I have the following code in C (am sort of para phrasing my code) :

```
struct row_content * LoadSheet(int); 

int main() {
   sheet_1 = LoadSheet(0);
   sheet_2 = LoadSheet(1);
}

struct row_content * LoadSheet(int sheet_index) {
   static struct row_content line[15];
      *
      *
      *
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Unclear since incomplete. What is `sheet_1` and how is it declared? Read more about [storage class specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). And read also [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) specification, i.e. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Read also about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: You could also have a static index which increases every time you use the function and return `line + i`, but it's a very brittle structure, I don't recommend.

Comment: @xing ... Thanks, let me try that out